# How to pull registry list from nexus?

Tags: registry, nexus

How to pull registry list with tags from nexus? I need to learn all of registries list with all tags.

Comment: You can find the information in the [API documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API). By saying _registry_ do you mean Nexus repositories or Docker registries? If you mean Docker registries then by _tags_ do you mean Docker image tags or Nexus component tags?

Comment: I mean Nexus repositories. I need a tool that it makes this job.

Comment: You can use the REST API from that documentation. You're looking for `GET /service/rest/v1/repositories`

Comment: If you're using the Sonatype tagging API, it means you're a professional customer and can also file a support request asking for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtain all repositories send a request `GET /service/rest/v1/repositories` (more information on this in the [Nexus documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API)).

To obtain all tags you can send request `GET /service/rest/v1/tags` (more information on this in the [Nexus documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Tagging)).

Comment: Thank for your response.